# AWS windows ec2 instance not able to access Jenkins dashboard from another windows ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, ping

I have created two windows ec2 on AWS. I have created Jenkins master on one of them. But not able to access that dashboard with ip address and port on other ec2. Both have same Security Group. I even tried allowing “All Traffic” for inbound rule but that also did not work.
The ping from one to another is also failing. Please suggest the solution.
My AWS plan is “Basic” (in case it has impact)

Tried allowing all traffic for inbound rule. Did not help.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring two machines inside the same security group you need to allow the security group to access itself.

So for example, I'm guessing this is the rule you added to your security group:

```
TCP, All Traffic, 0.0.0.0 (Which should work)
```

Instead you can have:

```
TCP, 8080 (Port for example), sg-xxxxx
```

Now machines that are protected by this security group will be able to access one another on this port.

Comment: Hi @Yaron, Thanks for extending help.
I have created the following rule. I have added the same SG in the rule. But still not able to access the machines.
There re two rules in the SG currently :
1. 
IP version:   -
Type: Custom TCP
Protocol: TCP
Port range: 8080
Source: -sg-******

2. For accessing from my machine added RDP
IP version: IPv4
Type: RDP
Protocol: TCP
Port range 3389
Source: 0.0.0.0/0

Please let me know what is blocking the machines from accessing each other.

Comment: Is this the only network interface? Are the routing rules correct? Is there an internal Windows firewall? Is the RDP service listening/running?

Comment: The RDP service is working well as I access both machines currently.

Comment: Are these machines on the same subnet? What are their IP addresses (if the prefix is the same just mention the last octet).

Comment: Yes they are on same subnet.
Also one thing to ask. Is "ping" the right check for connection from one ec2 to another ec2 ?

Comment: @S_K Not always, it can be blocked in some very creative ways, this is part of ICMP and if you want to see if TCP traffic is coming through it's a different story.